# Variable con respuesta del servicio undefined en otro metodo del componente

Tags: angular, typescript

Hola tengo un servicio que obtengo datos servicio1 y esos datos los necesito usar en otro metodo porque voy a filtrar informacion segun datos que tengo en comun con el serivicio2, entonces para la respuesta del servicio1 declare una variable y le asigno la respuesta del servicio1

```
dataOne:Array<any>= [];
```

el metodo del servicio1 lo llamo en el OnInit, pero al hacerle un console.log en el metodo del servicio2 esta undefined.

probe creando una variable de arreglo any y en el metodo que llama el servicio1 le hago un push pero nose si esa es una buena practica y es la manera correcta de hacerlo.

Comment: Saludos. Los `undefined` son resultado de que no existe; ojo es distinto de no inicializado. Revisa estes usando el nombre del método tal como esta donde esta creado `servicio2`.

Comment: Si estoy llamando al metodo correcto pero al hacer el console.log(this.data.One) esta undefined

Comment: Colocaste la definición `dataOne:Array<any>= [];` y estas haciendo `console.log(this.data.One)` debe ser `console.log(this.dataOne)`.

Comment: Si esta de esta manera console.log(this.dataOne) y sale undefined.